# Why does the Hilbert transform produce the Hilbert envelope?

Tags: geometric-interpretation

The Hilbert transform is often described as an improper integral.

It can be also characterized as a convolution between two functions.

But why is it these descriptions that produce the so called Hilbert envelope, which is the magnitude (i.e. absolute value) of the Hilbert transform? I cannot seem to grasp the intuition between the descriptions and the result.